# How to prevent my hover effect from applying to all the buttons on a mapped list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onmouseover, chakra-ui

I am trying to create a mouseOver hover effect on a button in a mapped list but it keeps applying to all the buttons how do I prevent this

```
   const [text, setText] = useState("Following")
   
   const handleChangeText = () => {
      setText( 'Unfollow'); 
    }
    const handleChange = () => {
      setText('Following');
    }

{relation?.followings?.data?.map((following:R, i) =>(
 <Button mr="-1rem" borderRadius="2rem" 
    onClick={(e)=>handleFollowUnfollow(e ,following?.username,'unfollow')} 
    _hover={{border: "1px solid #FFCCCB", color: "red", }} 
    onMouseOver={ handleChangeText} 
    onMouseLeave={handleChange}> 
    {text}
 </Button>
))}
```

Comment: You have to create a new step for each item or use an array

Comment: What is the condition on which you want to apply the effect?

Comment: if its hovered on the text on the button changes

Comment: Hi Chioma, your mapped items has no key, in react you need to set a key prop to the mapped list, this is how react identifies changed items. You can learn more about the key prop from here [React List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)